# Finding PDF for Irwin-Hall distribution given the MGF [Update]

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

The problem is the following:

> Given $X$ a random variable with MGF defined by
> $$\psi_X(t)=\left(\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right)^n$$
> deduce that the pdf of $X$ is
> $$f_X(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\mathbf{1}_{\{k\le x\}}(x)\frac{(x-k)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$
> for $x \in [0,n]$.

Initially, I tried to use the inversion formula on the characteristic function, because
$$f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e
^{-itx} \varphi_X(t)\,\text{d}t=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-itx}\psi_X(it)\,\text{d}t$$
but this seems to go nowhere since the integral that pops out is not very "solvable". In fact:
$$\psi_X(t)=\frac{1}{t^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{t(n-k)}(-1)^k \Longrightarrow f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{it(n-k-x)}}{t^n}\, \text{d}t$$
And I don't know how to proceed.

Then, I tried with induction on $n$ using the convolution formula in the following way:
$$\psi_X(t)=\psi_{X'}(t)\psi_Y(t)=\psi_{X'+Y}(t)\qquad \text{where} \qquad \psi_{X'}(t)=\left(\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right)^{n-1},\ \psi_Y(t)=\frac{e^t-1}{t}$$
So $X'$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables with $Y$ uniform on $(0,1)$ (i.e. $f_Y=\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}$) and $X'$ with pdf given (by induction hypothesis) by:
$$f_{X'}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}\mathbf{1}_{\{k\le x\}}(x)\frac{(x-k)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}$$
This means that
$$f_X(t)=f_{X'+Y}(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X'}(x)f_Y(t-x)\, \text{d}x\\=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{(n-2)!}\binom{n-1}{k}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(x-k)^{n-2}\mathbf{1}_{\{k\le x\}}(x)\mathbf{1}_{[0,n-1]}(x)\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(t-x)\, \text{d}x\\=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{(n-2)!}\binom{n-1}{k}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(x-k)^{n-2}\mathbf{1}_{[k,n-1]}(x)\mathbf{1}_{(t-1,t)}(x)\, \text{d}x$$
My problem is with those indicator functions, since $\mathbf{1}_{[k,n-1]}\mathbf{1}_{(t-1,t)}=\mathbf{1}_{[k,n-1]\cap (t-1,t)}$ and I don't understand how can I write this so that I have the "right" integration domain. How can I conclude? Is this path correct?

**Update:** I almost managed to find a full solution using the decomposition:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(x-k)^{n-2}\mathbf{1}_{[k,n-1]\cap(t-1,t)}(x)\, \text{d}x=\\ \mathbf{1}_{[k+1,n-1]}(t)\int_{t-1}^t (x-k)^{n-2}\, \text{d}x+\mathbf{1}_{[k,k+1)}(t)\int_{k}^t (x-k)^{n-2}\, \text{d}x+\mathbf{1}_{(n-1,n]}(t)\int_{t-1}^{n-1} (x-k)^{n-2}\, \text{d}x$$ valid for $k \in \{0,\dots,n-2\}$. Now the problem is that, if I suppose $t\le n-1$ the last addend is zero, and straightforward calculations bring to the thesis, but in the case $t \in (n-1,n]$ then the first two addends are zero, and we obtain the sum
$$f_X(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{(n-1)!}\binom{n-1}{k-1}((t-k)^{n-1}-(n-k)^{n-1})$$
And from this sum it seems to me that we cannot obtain the one that we want.

Where is the problem?

Comment: The integrals you wrote down don't exist as written but the Fourier transform is evaluable with contour integration. Your indicator functions are also not quite right, I think it should be $1_{k,n-1}$ and $1_{t-1,t}$

Comment: @FShrike you are right about the indicator functions. For the rest, can you be more specific? Why the integrals I wrote don't exists (especially the last ones)?

Comment: I meant the first ones, actually. $e^t/t^n$ has a problem at zero if you try to directly integrate it. I can fix that though, I'll write it up later

Comment: The integral can be computed thanks to the residue formula.